# Ember-table integration with Ember-model / Ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-model, ember-table, ember-1

I am trying to link ember-models to the ember-table to pull paginated records from the server and add them to the table when scrolling down.

I can get it working by just requesting my api url with page number like in the ajax example on http://addepar.github.io/ember-table/ but i cant figure out how to integrate it with ember-model to create and ember objects and then add them to the table.

Here is my code to just make an ajax request and add to table.  Can anyone tell me how i can change this to use ember-model / ember-data instead.

```
App.TableAjaxExample = Ember.Namespace.create()

App.TableAjaxExample.LazyDataSource = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend

  createGithubEvent: (row, event) ->

    row.set 'id',       event.id
    row.set 'name',  event.name
    row.set 'isLoaded',   yes

  requestGithubEvent: (page) ->

    content = @get 'content'
    start   = (page - 1) * 30
    end     = start + 30
    per_page = 40
    # something like this ???
    #App.Detail.find(type: 'companies', page: page, per_page: per_page).on 'didLoad', ->
    url = "http:/myurl.dev/admin/details.json?type=companies&page=#{page}&per_page=30"
    Ember.$.getJSON url, (json) =>
      json.details.forEach (event, index) =>
        row = content[start + index]
        @createGithubEvent row, event
    [start...end].forEach (index) ->
      content[index] = Ember.Object.create eventId: index, isLoaded: no

  objectAt: (index) ->

    content = @get 'content'
    #if index is content.get('length') - 1
    #  content.pushObjects(new Array(30))
    row = content[index]
    return row if row and not row.get('error')
    @requestGithubEvent Math.floor(index / 30 + 1)
    content[index]

App.TableAjaxExample.TableController =
Ember.Table.TableController.extend

  hasHeader: yes
  hasFooter: no
  numFixedColumns: 0
  numRows: 21054
  rowHeight: 35

  columns: Ember.computed ->

    columnNames = ['id', 'name']
    columns = columnNames.map (key, index) ->
      Ember.Table.ColumnDefinition.create
        columnWidth: 150
        headerCellName: key.w()
        contentPath: key

    columns
  .property()

  content: Ember.computed ->
    App.TableAjaxExample.LazyDataSource.create

      content: new Array(@get('numRows'))
  .property 'numRows'
```

Is the possible or does this slow it down to much?

Thanks for the help.
Rick

Comment: Rick, is there a reason you haven't accepted my answer below?

Comment: sorry Jeremy thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a JSBin that I got working with Ember Data and the `RESTAdapter`: http://jsbin.com/eVOgUrE/3/edit

It works very similarly to the AJAX loading example, but uses Ember Data to load the data.  I created a `RowProxy` object that is returned immediately to the Ember Table so that it can render a row.  After Ember Data loads a page full of data it sets the `object` property on the `RowProxy` which updates the view.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

// The main model that will be loaded into Ember Table 
App.Gallery = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  smallUrl: DS.attr('string')
});

// This is a temporary buffer object that sits between
// Ember Table and the model object (Gallery, in this case).
App.RowProxy = Ember.Object.extend({
  object:null,
  getObjectProperty : function(prop){
    var obj = this.get('object');
    if(obj){ console.log(prop + " : " + obj.get(prop)); }
    return obj ? obj.get(prop) : 'loading...';
  },
  isLoaded : function(){ return !!this.get('object'); }.property('object'),
  name : function(){ return this.getObjectProperty('name'); }.property('object.name'),
  id : function(){ return this.getObjectProperty('id'); }.property('object.id'),
  smallUrl : function(){ return this.getObjectProperty('smallUrl'); }.property('object.smallUrl')
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  tableController: Ember.computed(function() {
    return Ember.get('App.TableAjaxExample.TableController').create({
      // We need to pass in the store so that the table can use it
      store : this.get('store')
    });
  })
});

App.TableAjaxExample = Ember.Namespace.create();

App.TableAjaxExample.ImageTableCell = Ember.Table.TableCell.extend({
  templateName: 'img-table-cell',
  classNames: 'img-table-cell'
});

App.TableAjaxExample.LazyDataSource = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
  requestPage : function(page){
    var content, end, start, url, _i, _results,
      _this = this;

    content = this.get('content');
    start = (page - 1) * 3;
    end = start + 3;

    // Find galleries and then update the RowProxy to hold a gallery as 'object'
    this.get('store').find('gallery',{page_size:3,page:page}).then(function(galleries){
      return galleries.forEach(function(gallery, index) {    
        var position = start + index;
        content[position].set('object',gallery);
      });  
    });

    // Fill the 'content' array with RowProxy objects
    // Taken from the 'requestGithubEvent' method of the original example
    return (function() {
      _results = [];
      for (var _i = start; start <= end ? _i < end : _i > end; start <= end ? _i++ : _i--){ _results.push(_i); }
      return _results;
    }).apply(this).forEach(function(index) {
      return content[index] = App.RowProxy.create({
        index: index
      });
    });
  },

  objectAt: function(index) {
    var content, row;
    content = this.get('content');
    row = content[index];
    if (row && !row.get('error')) {
      return row;
    }
    this.requestPage(Math.floor(index / 3 + 1));
    return content[index];
  }
});

App.TableAjaxExample.TableController = Ember.Table.TableController.extend({
  hasHeader: true,
  hasFooter: false,
  numFixedColumns: 0,
  numRows: 19,
  rowHeight: 35,
  columns: Ember.computed(function() {
    var avatar, columnNames, columns;

    avatar = Ember.Table.ColumnDefinition.create({
      columnWidth: 80,
      headerCellName: 'smallUrl',
      tableCellViewClass: 'App.TableAjaxExample.ImageTableCell',
      contentPath: 'smallUrl'
    });
    columnNames = ['id', 'name'];
    columns = columnNames.map(function(key, index) {
      return Ember.Table.ColumnDefinition.create({
        columnWidth: 150,
        headerCellName: key.w(),
        contentPath: key
      });
    });
    columns.unshift(avatar);
    return columns;
  }).property(),
  content: Ember.computed(function() {
    return App.TableAjaxExample.LazyDataSource.create({
      content: new Array(this.get('numRows')),
      store : this.get('store')
    });
  }).property('numRows')
});


App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://files.cloudhdr.com/api/v1/public',
  // This is here to use underscores in API params
  pathForType: function(type) {
    var underscored = Ember.String.underscore(type);
    return Ember.String.pluralize(underscored);
  }
});

// Everything below is all here to use underscores in API params.
// You may or may not need this.

DS.RESTSerializer.reopen({
  modelTypeFromRoot: function(root) {
    console.log("modelTypeFromRoot " + root);
    var camelized = Ember.String.camelize(root);
    return Ember.String.singularize(camelized);
  }
});

App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalize: function(type, hash, property) {
    var normalized = {}, normalizedProp;

    for (var prop in hash) {
      if (prop.substr(-3) === '_id') {
        // belongsTo relationships
        normalizedProp = prop.slice(0, -3);
      } else if (prop.substr(-4) === '_ids') {
        // hasMany relationship
        normalizedProp = Ember.String.pluralize(prop.slice(0, -4));
      } else {
        // regualarAttribute
        normalizedProp = prop;
      }

      normalizedProp = Ember.String.camelize(normalizedProp);
      normalized[normalizedProp] = hash[prop];
    }

    return this._super(type, normalized, property);
  }
});
```

Comment: would this solution work with the [FixtureAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.FixtureAdapter.html) too?

Comment: @Ashraf it does, however you probably would need to customize it a little, my tests showed a couble of problems like: if you have `numRows` higher, than the amount of fixtures, then you'll get an error (so.. for 2 fixtures, your numrows can be 1 or 2.. not higher)

+1, tyvm Jeremy